# Reading and Storing csv data line by line in a postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

I want to copy csv data from different files and then store in a table. But the problem is, the number of column differes in each csv files, So some csv file have 3 columns while some have 4.  So if there are 4 columns in a file, I want to simply ignore the fourth column and save only first three.

Using following code, I can copy data into the table, if there are only 3 columns,

```
CREATE TABLE ImportCSVTable (
          name varchar(100),
                  address varchar(100),
                  phone varchar(100));




COPY ImportCSVTable (name , address , phone)
         FROM 'path'
        WITH DELIMITER ';' CSV QUOTE '"';
```

But I am looking forward to check each row individually and then store it in the table.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to read and store it one line at a time, the [Python csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) should make it easy to read the first 3 columns from your CSV file regardless of any extra columns.

You can construct an INSERT statement and execute it with your preferred Python-PostGreSQL module.  I have used pyPgSQL in the past; don't know what's current now.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
filesource = 'PeopleAndResources.csv'
with open(filesource, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        statement = "INSERT INTO ImportCSVTable " + \
        "(name, address, phone) " + \
        "VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')" % (tuple(row[0:3]))
        #execute statement
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a text utility to chop off the fourth column. That way, all your input files will have three columns. Some combination of `awk`, `cut`, and `sed` should take care of it for you, but it depends on what your columns look like.

Comment: Thank you, But I want to read file line by line, and I found that I should use STDIN for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just make your input table have a fourth column that is nullable, then after the import drop the extra column.